# Selecting nth-child skipping hidden elements

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I'm looking for a CSS only (no JS) way to ignore hidden elements in nth-child counts. Is this possible?

I've got this HTML:

```
<div class="gallery-item"><img src="http://placehold.it/150x150"></div>
<div class="gallery-item"><img src="http://placehold.it/150x150"></div>
<div class="gallery-item empty"></div>
<div class="gallery-item"><img src="http://placehold.it/150x150"></div>
<div class="gallery-item empty"></div>
<div class="gallery-item"><img src="http://placehold.it/150x150"></div>
<div class="gallery-item"><img src="http://placehold.it/150x150"></div>
```

I'm trying to target every second gallery-item that is not empty, but this isn't working:

`.gallery-item:not(.empty):nth-child(2n) {}`

I don't want to use JS because this is a complex site that has many breakpoints and I don't want to add onresize listeners for something this basic.

Comment: As far as I know this is not possible with CSS because `nth-child(2n)` would point to every 2nd child and it would get the style if it also has gallery-item class but not empty class.

Comment: Ah, sorry for that typo error. Did not notice :(

Answer (score 1):

This may be a zero-post, because it uses JS. However it seems to be only option in this case. You didn't want to use JS, which I understand. But as far no-one comes with CSS only solution, at least consider this: http://codepen.io/zvona/pen/jPZYNx

```
var galleryItems = document.querySelectorAll('.gallery-item:not(.empty)');

[].forEach.call(galleryItems, function(item, i) {
  item.classList.toggle('notEmptyAndEven', i % 2)
});
```

and then just add `.notEmptyAndEven` selector and the CSS rules you need.

Answer (score -2):

You must use below code to target the second item

```
.gallery-item:not(.empty):nth-child(2) { //not :nth-child(2n)
    background:#ddd
}
```

Link [JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/g2ad13ou/1/)

Comment: Question states *target every second gallery-item that is not empty* and not just the second item.